# Ajax source return in response multiple labels. How I can add new line after first label

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In the `$.ajax({` I return labels with their values but I want second label beneath first one, I tried `+ "\n" +`. A better question is how I insert `html` there? Because later maybe I want to insert tables or something else to look well.

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }

    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Jobs/GetTags",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: extractLast(request.term)},
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {                               
                            label: item.Name + "\n" + item.Description,
                            value: item.Name,                               
                        };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },

        focus: function () {
            return false;
        },

        search: function () {
            // custom minLength
            var term = extractLast(this.value);
            if (term.length < 2) {
                return false;
            }
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        },

        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () { }
        }
    });
})
```

Here is the razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <p>
        Tags @Html.TextBox("search")    
    </p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I added at the end following:

```
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (li, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label1 + "</a>" + "<br />" + item.label2 + "</a>").before("<br />")
            .appendTo(li);
    };
```